# Solving $ax+b$ (mod n) = $cx+d$ (mod n)

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How does one solve questions of $ax+b$ (mod n) = $cx+d$ (mod n) form?

I know that if $b,d$ are $0$ then, I can take multiples of $n$ as solutions for x.

but what if $b,n$ are not zero?

Under what conditions do solutions exist?

Comment: Should it be  $ax+b\equiv cx+d \pmod n$?

Answer (score 2):

What you've written is essentially $ax + b \equiv cx + d \pmod n$ (as mentioned in a comment).

You can rearrange to: $(a-c)x \equiv (d-b) \pmod n$, which gives the solution $x \equiv (d-b)(a-c)^{-1} \pmod n$, where $(a-c)^{-1}$ is the [Modular Multiplicative Inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $a-c$ modulo $n$ (if it exists). The modular inverse exists if and only if $a-c$ is coprime to $n$.

Comment: So the answer is incomplete, as it does not cover non-coprime cases.

Comment: solutions exists if gcd(a-c,n) divides (d-b)??

Comment: right, solutions exists if and only if $\text{gcd}(a-c,n)\mid d-b$. Rename: $a-c\to a, d-b\to b$ and let $d=\text{gcd}(a,n)\mid b, a=a_1d, n=n_1d, b=b_1d, $ Deleting common factor $d$ we have $a_1\equiv b_1\pmod{n_1} $ where $a_1$ is coprime to $n_1.$

Answer (score 2):

$$ ax + b \pmod n \equiv cx + d \quad \pmod n $$
$$ (a - c)x \equiv d-b \pmod n$$

$$ Ax \equiv B \quad \pmod n$$
where $A  = a-c, \; B = d - b$. Thus,

1) If $ a \equiv c \pmod n$:

- If $b \equiv d \pmod n$: $x$ is any integer.
- Otherwise, no solution.

2) If $a \not\equiv c \pmod n$:

- If $A$ has a multiplicative inverse$\pmod n$ called C, the solution will be:
  $ x \equiv BC \pmod n$.
- Otherwise, no solution.

Note the multiplicative inverse$\pmod n$ can be found by tabulating the product of $ij$ in a square table where the rows are numbered $i = 0,1,...,n-1$ and the columns are numbered $j=0,1,...n-1$. To find the multiplicative inverse of each $i$, find the value of $j$ that makes $ij \equiv 1\pmod n$. In general, not all $i$ have a multiplicative inverse.